# Question about usage of express-validator with nested object

Tags: express, express-validator

I am trying to verify whether the `title` of the board is not empty. If my request is sent in the format of `{title: ""}` I am able to do `check("title").not().isEmpty()`, and it works just fine.

However, if I am sending the request like this:

```js
board: {
  "title": "Something
}
```

Then the check from the above doesn't work as I am always getting the `title` to be `undefined`. How can I test for the `title` being not empty in this case using express-validator?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It should be `check("board.title").not().isEmpty()`